Не могу локально открыть в браузере сайт справочник на Андроиде, (сайт как папка со всеми страницами)
Есть сайт справочник, его можно скачать и открывать как на пк так и на смартфоне.
http://sprav.dvigatel.org/download_directory.html
Устанавливать его как папку на устройстройстве Redmi note 8 pro
В хроме прописывал
file:///storage/emulated/0/spr/index.html
spr - название папки сайта
Таким образом я мог пользоваться сайтом без интернета
Сменил телефон на Redmi note 13 pro
Установил точно также, но при вводе cылки вижу сообщения, типа ошибка ввода,поврежден файл, нету прав доступа.
Даже просто в корневую папку немогу войти через хром - сообщения тоже самое. Я думаю что проблема как раз таки в правах доступа , но как их получить не знаю
Можно как-то решить проблему зарание спасибо.

Добрый день, не помешало бы само сообщение об ошибке. Вы пробовали открывать файл из проводника через хром?

нельзя жестко прописывать пути в Андроид ОС. Используйте спец. функции типа getExternalFilesDir

@Style-7, в адресной строке браузера?)

Никак вы не можете разрешить хрому доступ к вашим файлам, если он сам его не запрашивает. Без сторонних решений, либо разработки собственного приложения со встроенным браузером или локальным сервером здесь не обойтись. В сетях где-то были конструкторы приложений из сайтов, но после запрета публикации такого добра в маркет, большинство из них закрылось. И, кстати, вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта - здесь помогают решать проблемы, связанные с разработкой ПО, но не пользования чужим готовым.

@woesss В своем приложении.

Спасибо за ваши ответы

@ДенисБелозёров да, на старом андроиде всё работает как мне нужно, а вот на новом нет , не могут понять куда копать, чтобы решить мою проблему

Вам же в первом комменте сказали что делать: зайдите в проводник, нажмите на html и выберете chrome

попробуйте пройти к сайту через проводник и кликом по index.html открыть его в хроме, возможно Ваш телефон по другому строит локальные пути, тогда когда сайт откроется вы увидите рабочий путь к странице в адресной строке браузера.

если вариант выше не сработает, попробуйте вот это приложение
